# Resolve ORA-00979: not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

Maybe this is an easy one for some smart one to answer, I think the statemant is simple but not for me...
The original statement uses a MAX for finding correct row but now there is a problem and I need the MIN as the aggregator to find the correct row.
But then the problem with CASE togheter with GROUP BY and I get the ORA-00979: not a group by expression

I have searched and tried to follow other people with the same error and the suggested solutions but I dont get it to work due to a lot of trail and error.
The statement is a small portion of the SQL

This statement works and get me the row(single column) with MAX

```
SELECT
    TRANSMAIN.TRANSEX AS TRANSEX,
    MAX(TRANSLOG.TRANSIK)AS TRANSIK
FROM
    tmsdat.TRANSLOG TRANSLOG,
    tmsdat.TRANSMAIN TRANSMAIN,
    tmsdat.TRCBUS TRCBUS
WHERE
    TRANSMAIN.TRCBUSNO=TRCBUS.TRCBUSNO
    AND TRANSMAIN.TRANSIK >=5246867 
    AND TRANSMAIN.TRANSIK=TRANSLOG.TRANSIK

GROUP
    BY TRANSMAIN.TRANSEX
```

But this modified statement gets the error
I understand it is NOT possible to use the CASE in there but just to explain what needs to be done.

```
SELECT
    TRANSMAIN.TRANSEX AS TRANSEX,
    (case when  TRANSMAIN.TRCBUSNO = 1282
    MIN(TRANSLOG.TRANSIK) else
    MAX(TRANSLOG.TRANSIK) end ) AS TRANSIK
FROM
    tmsdat.TRANSLOG TRANSLOG,
    tmsdat.TRANSMAIN TRANSMAIN,
    tmsdat.TRCBUS TRCBUS
WHERE
    TRANSMAIN.TRCBUSNO=TRCBUS.TRCBUSNO
    AND TRANSMAIN.TRANSIK >=5246867 
    AND TRANSMAIN.TRANSIK=TRANSLOG.TRANSIK

GROUP
    BY TRANSMAIN.TRANSEX
```

Hope someone sees an easy solution.
Regards /Stefan

Comment: you should add TRANSMAIN.TRCBUSNO to the "group by" expression alongside TRANSMAIN.TRANSEX

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Either include `TRCBUSNO` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT tm.TRANSEX AS TRANSEX,
       CASE
       WHEN tm.TRCBUSNO = 1282
       THEN MIN(tl.TRANSIK)
       ELSE MAX(tl.TRANSIK)
       END AS TRANSIK
FROM   tmsdat.TRANSLOG tl
       INNER JOIN tmsdat.TRANSMAIN tm
       ON (tm.TRANSIK=tl.TRANSIK)
       INNER JOIN tmsdat.TRCBUS tb
       ON (tm.TRCBUSNO=tb.TRCBUSNO)
WHERE  tm.TRANSIK >=5246867 
GROUP BY
       tm.TRANSEX,
       tm.trcbusno
```

Or else aggregate by that column:

```sql
SELECT tm.TRANSEX AS TRANSEX,
       CASE
       WHEN MIN(tm.TRCBUSNO) = 1282
       THEN MIN(tl.TRANSIK)
       ELSE MAX(tl.TRANSIK)
       END AS TRANSIK
FROM   tmsdat.TRANSLOG tl
       INNER JOIN tmsdat.TRANSMAIN tm
       ON (tm.TRANSIK=tl.TRANSIK)
       INNER JOIN tmsdat.TRCBUS tb
       ON (tm.TRCBUSNO=tb.TRCBUSNO)
WHERE  tm.TRANSIK >=5246867 
GROUP BY
       tm.TRANSEX
```

or:

```sql
SELECT tm.TRANSEX AS TRANSEX,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN tm.TRCBUSNO = 1282 THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN MIN(tl.TRANSIK)
       ELSE MAX(tl.TRANSIK)
       END AS TRANSIK
FROM   tmsdat.TRANSLOG tl
       INNER JOIN tmsdat.TRANSMAIN tm
       ON (tm.TRANSIK=tl.TRANSIK)
       INNER JOIN tmsdat.TRCBUS tb
       ON (tm.TRCBUSNO=tb.TRCBUSNO)
WHERE  tm.TRANSIK >=5246867 
GROUP BY
       tm.TRANSEX
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers
All options worked 